# AlertDialog not refreshing data

Tags: java, android

```
public void setFileName(String inMake, String inModel) {
    //sets spinner to get year
    filename = filename.concat(inMake);
    filename = filename.concat(inModel);
    filename = filename.concat(".txt");

    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    BufferedReader reader;
    AssetManager assetManager = MainActivity.getContext().getAssets();
    List<String> testYears = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(filename);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istr));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            testYears.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("message: ",e.getMessage());
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder yearDialog = new Builder(this);
    yearDialog.setTitle("Select Year");

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, testYears);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    yearDialog.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            year = Integer.parseInt(adapter.getItem(which));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Year : " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = yearDialog.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

I'm attempting to retrieve a user choice via an alertdialog. The array it uses for the arrayAdapter is based on the input of the function(string inmake, string inmodel) which are passed from outside the activity. This method seems to work perfectly - but only the first time. If I send in new string information to the method, it doesn't show any options in the alertdialog.

Any help would be much obliged.

Comment: Please use notifyDataSetChange()  after loading adapter.

Comment: @BhunnuBaba
My bad, i moved the notifyDataSetChanged() after i loaded the adapter, and the result is the same.

Comment: Upload bath line of code one, by which you fill adapter initially second, by which you are updating your adapter.